# Shiny app on mobile interrupted by screen lock

Tags: ios, r, shiny

I have a Shiny app that I want to use mainly from an iPhone. However, when my phone goes to lockscreen (from manual click or after 30 seconds of inactivity), the Shinyapp disconnects from the server. I have reproduced this with various apps, so I do not believe it is a code issue.

I cannot find any documentation on how to make the app continue to run while the lock screen is on. Is there a way to do this?